# Can't declare a 2D vector

Tags: c++, macos, vector, 2d-vector

I get 3 errors :

- First, I want to declare a 2D vector but I get the error : ***expected ';' at end of declaration [29, 43]*** ;
- I get the error : ***invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'std::vectorstd::vector<int >') [39, 5]*** ;
- Third error : ***no operator "<<" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::__1::ostream << std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator>>> [39, 15]***.

I don't understand why, my code seems to be correct. I've tried with a 1D vector but I get the same error. For me, my syntaxe is correct. For the operator's issue, I've seen plenty of topics about it but no one could help me in my case.

I'm on Mac using Clang with C++20 in VS Code. I've checked my settings, my configurations etc, all seems to be up-to-date and correct.

Can someone explain me what's the problem here please ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector < std::vector <int> > interchange(std::vector< std::vector<int> > vect)
{
    /* In : a 2d vector containing only binaries.
    Out : the previous 2d vector with the binaries interchanged. */

    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < vect[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if (vect[i][j] == 0)
            {
                vect[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else 
            {
                vect[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }    
    }

    return vect;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector < std::vector <int> > vect 
    {
        {1, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 1}
    };
    
    std::vector < std::vector <int> > a = interchange(vect);

    std::cout << a << std::endl; // making sure that my function works
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n" << "This is my program!\n"; // making sure that the program runs
}
```

.vscode configuration files :

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++20"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "clang++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++2a",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "-g",
          "${file}",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/E1Do1RhrhXZQPpml). Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: compiler version?

Comment: Maybe you are using C++03? Then upgrade to C++11 or later.

Comment: Sounds like compiler is set to c++03 or lower

Comment: Ok, I was using C++98. I upgraded to C++20. I still have the same error code but it compiles. I added some informations in my post.

Comment: "I still have the same error code" and "it compiles" are contradictory information. You either have a compiler error and it doesn't compile OR you don't have compiler errors and it compiles. You can't have compilation errors and still compile.

Comment: @bolov: It’s unfortunately common for people to use an IDE that is configured to use a different compiler or different options to display error annotations.

Comment: well the post is a mess at the moment. "I get the error  expected ';'  ..." and " My code is running (as "Hello world" appears in the terminal) " and "but my function is not working." - what does not working mean? The OP should really clarify and remove contradictory information from the post.

Comment: @bolov: I know it's contradictory, but it's really what's happening, I was confused too, it seems like the build just skip the vector declaration and the function call too, it's strange. I'm used to code on windows, not on mac so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: "as nothing is return by it" how did you determine that? You don't use the return value so how do you know "nothing is returned"? What do you expect the behavior of this program to be?

Comment: @bolov: my function return a vector. The vector needed as a parameter for the function is not declared because of the error code. Because of the undeclared parameter, the function is not working, or "running" if you prefer. That's how I interpret it.

Comment: If your program runs (aka displays "hello world") then it has no compilation errors. If you still somehow see compilation errors and still see the program running then: there are a few scenarios: you see errors from intellisense (squigles called in VSCode) - somehow intellisense is stuck on the old C++98 or its cache is not refreshed and displays old errors. Nevertheless intellisense has actually nothing to do with the actual compilation and running of the program.

Comment: Another scenario is that you somehow compile/run an old version of the code or another program altogether than the one you are editing (yes it can happen, we are humans). So: do not connect the error you are seeing with the program running: the program that is running 100% did not have/does not have compilation errors, otherwise it wouldn't have compiled.

Comment: To clear the error (which has nothing to do with the running program): make sure intellisense matches the compiler standard (c++20); clear intellisense cache (or rebuild cache, whatever is called); restart VSCode.

Comment: to see if your function is actually working: Store the result of the function and print it (the inverted vector)

Comment: To make sure you are running the program you are editing: change the output to something unique, e.g. `std::cout << "Hello World\n" << "This is my program\n";` and observe if the change happens when you run the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution.

For the "***expected ';' at end of declaration [29, 43]***" error:

The VS Code IntelliSense is showing an error, but because the compiler does not found any error, my code runs. As a solution, we can ignore it, while it does not block the compiling process. Even sometimes, the error does not appear... It may be a bug from VS Code, as my JSON files are setup correctly and everything up-to-date.

For the invalids operands errors:

That's because we can't "cout" a vector apparently. So in order to print a vector, we have to create a function for it.

Here are my files, everything works. For the JSON files, you can copy mines, but you will problably just have to change some paths:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void invert(std::vector< std::vector <int> > vector)
{
    /* In : a 2d vector containing only binaries.
    Out : the previous 2d vector with the binaries interchanged. */

    for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < vector[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if (vector[i][j] == 0) vector[i][j] = 1;
            else vector[i][j] = 0;
            std::cout << vector[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void print2DVector(std::vector< std::vector <int> > vector)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < vector[i].size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << vector[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector < std::vector <int> > vector 
    {
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}
    };
    
    print2DVector(vector);
    std::cout << "\nInverting...\n\n";
    invert(vector);
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++20"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "clang++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++2a",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "-g",
          "${file}",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Terminal:

```
1 0 0 0 1 
1 1 0 1 1 
0 1 0 1 0 

Inverting...

0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
1 0 1 0 1
```

Good luck on your coding projects!

Answer (score 0):

The code is valid, and [runs](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/862724f706468a16) (though watch out for those signed/unsigned comparisons, per the compiler warnings!).

The error message you describe suggests that either your compiler, or your IDE's "IntelliSense" equivalent (depending on where you see the error message) does not understand C++11's uniform initialisation syntax in this context.

Ensure that all C++ language settings are "correct", and that all tools in your environment are up to date.

Comment: I've checked everything but it's still not working... I have now other issues. Maybe I messed up with something. I edited my questions and added more informations.